# Apply random rotation to canvas particles

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to update an existing [particle animation](https://www.cssscript.com/confetti-falling-animation/). In this demo, the particles are just lines with different `lineWidth`s with random sizes and rotation as they fall down.

My goal is to replace the lines with a different shape, which looks like the image below keeping everything else as is.

[image]

I've already changed the shape, but I'm having a couple issues:

1. It doesn't rotate anymore like in the original demo link posted above.
2. Since, I replaced the lines with an image of the shape, I'm also facing performance issues if I increase the particles.
3. If I randomize the size, it keeps updating the size of the shape constantly without keeping the first random size.

   ```
   context.drawImage(svg, x, y, 20, 40)
                     |
                     v
   context.drawImage(svg, x, y, Math.random() * 20, Math.random() * 40)
   ```

Could anybody point me in the right direction on I should go about fixing the above. Appreciate any help!

```js
var confetti = {
  maxCount: 150,     //set max confetti count
  speed: 1,          //set the particle animation speed
  frameInterval: 30, //the confetti animation frame interval in milliseconds
  alpha: 1.0,        //the alpha opacity of the confetti (between 0 and 1, where 1 is opaque and 0 is invisible)
  gradient: false,   //whether to use gradients for the confetti particles
  start: null,       //call to start confetti animation (with optional timeout in milliseconds, and optional min and max random confetti count)
  stop: null,        //call to stop adding confetti
  toggle: null,      //call to start or stop the confetti animation depending on whether it's already running
  pause: null,       //call to freeze confetti animation
  resume: null,      //call to unfreeze confetti animation
  togglePause: null, //call to toggle whether the confetti animation is paused
  remove: null,      //call to stop the confetti animation and remove all confetti immediately
  isPaused: null,    //call and returns true or false depending on whether the confetti animation is paused
  isRunning: null    //call and returns true or false depending on whether the animation is running
};

(function() {
  confetti.start = startConfetti;
  confetti.stop = stopConfetti;
  confetti.toggle = toggleConfetti;
  confetti.pause = pauseConfetti;
  confetti.resume = resumeConfetti;
  confetti.togglePause = toggleConfettiPause;
  confetti.isPaused = isConfettiPaused;
  confetti.remove = removeConfetti;
  confetti.isRunning = isConfettiRunning;
  var supportsAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  var colors = ["rgba(30,144,255,", "rgba(107,142,35,", "rgba(255,215,0,", "rgba(255,192,203,", "rgba(106,90,205,", "rgba(173,216,230,", "rgba(238,130,238,", "rgba(152,251,152,", "rgba(70,130,180,", "rgba(244,164,96,", "rgba(210,105,30,", "rgba(220,20,60,"];
  var streamingConfetti = false;
  var animationTimer = null;
  var pause = false;
  var lastFrameTime = Date.now();
  var particles = [];
  var waveAngle = 0;
  var context = null;

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  function resetParticle(particle, width, height) {
    particle.color = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0] + (confetti.alpha + ")");
    particle.color2 = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0] + (confetti.alpha + ")");
    particle.x = getRandomInt(0, width);
    particle.y = getRandomInt(-height / 2, 0);
    particle.diameter = Math.random() * 10 + 5;
    particle.tilt = Math.random() * 10 - 10;
    particle.tiltAngleIncrement = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.05;
    particle.tiltAngle = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    return particle;
  }

  function toggleConfettiPause() {
    if (pause)
      resumeConfetti();
    else
      pauseConfetti();
  }

  function isConfettiPaused() {
    return pause;
  }

  function pauseConfetti() {
    pause = true;
  }

  function resumeConfetti() {
    pause = false;
    runAnimation();
  }

  function runAnimation() {
    if (pause)
      return;
    else if (particles.length === 0) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      animationTimer = null;
    } else {
      var now = Date.now();
      var delta = now - lastFrameTime;
      if (!supportsAnimationFrame || delta > confetti.frameInterval) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        updateParticles();
        drawParticles(context);
        lastFrameTime = now - (delta % confetti.frameInterval);
      }
      animationTimer = requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);
    }
  }

  function startConfetti(timeout, min, max) {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(callback) {
          return window.setTimeout(callback, confetti.frameInterval);
        };
    })();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("confetti-canvas");
    if (canvas === null) {
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.setAttribute("id", "confetti-canvas");
      canvas.setAttribute("style", "display:block;z-index:999999;pointer-events:none;position:fixed;top:0");
      document.body.prepend(canvas);
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      }, true);
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    } else if (context === null)
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var count = confetti.maxCount;
    if (min) {
      if (max) {
        if (min == max)
          count = particles.length + max;
        else {
          if (min > max) {
            var temp = min;
            min = max;
            max = temp;
          }
          count = particles.length + ((Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0);
        }
      } else
        count = particles.length + min;
    } else if (max)
      count = particles.length + max;
    while (particles.length < count)
      particles.push(resetParticle({}, width, height));
    streamingConfetti = true;
    pause = false;
    runAnimation();
    if (timeout) {
      window.setTimeout(stopConfetti, timeout);
    }
  }

  function stopConfetti() {
    streamingConfetti = false;
  }

  function removeConfetti() {
    stop();
    pause = false;
    particles = [];
  }

  function toggleConfetti() {
    if (streamingConfetti)
      stopConfetti();
    else
      startConfetti();
  }

  function isConfettiRunning() {
    return streamingConfetti;
  }

  function drawParticles(context) {
    var particle;
    var x, y, x2, y2;
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      particle = particles[i];
      particleWidth = particle.diameter;
      x2 = particle.x + particle.tilt;
      x = x2 + particle.diameter / 2;
      y = particle.y;

      var svg = new Image();
      svg.src = 'https://i.postimg.cc/TPBmVXH1/confetti.png';
      context.drawImage(svg, x, y, 20, 40)

      /*context.beginPath();
      context.lineWidth = particle.diameter;
      x2 = particle.x + particle.tilt;
      x = x2 + particle.diameter / 2;
      y2 = particle.y + particle.tilt + particle.diameter / 2;
      if (confetti.gradient) {
       var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(x, particle.y, x2, y2);
       gradient.addColorStop("0", particle.color);
       gradient.addColorStop("1.0", particle.color2);
       context.strokeStyle = gradient;
      } else
       context.strokeStyle = particle.color;
      context.moveTo(x, particle.y);
      context.lineTo(x2, y2);
      context.stroke();*/
    }
  }

  function updateParticles() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var particle;
    waveAngle += 0.01;
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      particle = particles[i];
      if (!streamingConfetti && particle.y < -15)
        particle.y = height + 100;
      else {
        particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncrement;
        particle.x += Math.sin(waveAngle) - 0.5;
        particle.y += (Math.cos(waveAngle) + particle.diameter + confetti.speed) * 0.5;
        particle.tilt = Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle) * 15;
      }
      if (particle.x > width + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > height) {
        if (streamingConfetti && particles.length <= confetti.maxCount)
          resetParticle(particle, width, height);
        else {
          particles.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  startConfetti(5000, 20, 25)
})();
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is what I did:

1. I changed `drawParticles` to apply the `particle.tilt`.
2. I moved the `svg` variable to the top so it is reused and not loaded multiple times.
3. I did set the random size in `resetParticle` so it does not change afterwards.

```js
var confetti = {
  maxCount: 150,  //set max confetti count
  speed: 1,   //set the particle animation speed
  frameInterval: 30, //the confetti animation frame interval in milliseconds
  alpha: 1.0,   //the alpha opacity of the confetti (between 0 and 1, where 1 is opaque and 0 is invisible)
  gradient: false, //whether to use gradients for the confetti particles
  start: null,  //call to start confetti animation (with optional timeout in milliseconds, and optional min and max random confetti count)
  stop: null,   //call to stop adding confetti
  toggle: null,  //call to start or stop the confetti animation depending on whether it's already running
  pause: null,  //call to freeze confetti animation
  resume: null,  //call to unfreeze confetti animation
  togglePause: null, //call to toggle whether the confetti animation is paused
  remove: null,  //call to stop the confetti animation and remove all confetti immediately
  isPaused: null,  //call and returns true or false depending on whether the confetti animation is paused
  isRunning: null  //call and returns true or false depending on whether the animation is running
};

(function () {
  confetti.start = startConfetti;
  confetti.stop = stopConfetti;
  confetti.toggle = toggleConfetti;
  confetti.pause = pauseConfetti;
  confetti.resume = resumeConfetti;
  confetti.togglePause = toggleConfettiPause;
  confetti.isPaused = isConfettiPaused;
  confetti.remove = removeConfetti;
  confetti.isRunning = isConfettiRunning;
  var supportsAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  var colors = ["rgba(30,144,255,", "rgba(107,142,35,", "rgba(255,215,0,", "rgba(255,192,203,", "rgba(106,90,205,", "rgba(173,216,230,", "rgba(238,130,238,", "rgba(152,251,152,", "rgba(70,130,180,", "rgba(244,164,96,", "rgba(210,105,30,", "rgba(220,20,60,"];
  var streamingConfetti = false;
  var animationTimer = null;
  var pause = false;
  var lastFrameTime = Date.now();
  var particles = [];
  var waveAngle = 0;
  var context = null;
  
  var sizes = []; 
  var svg = new Image();
  
  svg.src = 'https://i.postimg.cc/TPBmVXH1/confetti.png';

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  function resetParticle(particle, width, height) {
    particle.color = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0] + (confetti.alpha + ")");
    particle.color2 = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0] + (confetti.alpha + ")");
    particle.x = getRandomInt(0, width);
    particle.y = getRandomInt(-height / 2, 0);
    particle.diameter = Math.random() * 10 + 5;
    particle.tilt = Math.random() * 10 - 10;
    particle.tiltAngleIncrement = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.05;
    particle.tiltAngle = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    
    particle.width = Math.random() * 20
    particle.height = Math.random() * 40
    
    return particle;
  }

  function toggleConfettiPause() {
    if (pause)
      resumeConfetti();
    else
      pauseConfetti();
  }

  function isConfettiPaused() {
    return pause;
  }

  function pauseConfetti() {
    pause = true;
  }

  function resumeConfetti() {
    pause = false;
    runAnimation();
  }

  function runAnimation() {
    if (pause)
      return;
    else if (particles.length === 0) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      animationTimer = null;
    } else {
      var now = Date.now();
      var delta = now - lastFrameTime;
      if (!supportsAnimationFrame || delta > confetti.frameInterval) {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        updateParticles();
        drawParticles(context);
        lastFrameTime = now - (delta % confetti.frameInterval);
      }
      animationTimer = requestAnimationFrame(runAnimation);
    }
  }

  function startConfetti(timeout, min, max) {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    window.requestAnimationFrame = (function () {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (callback) {
          return window.setTimeout(callback, confetti.frameInterval);
        };
    })();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("confetti-canvas");
    if (canvas === null) {
      canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.setAttribute("id", "confetti-canvas");
      canvas.setAttribute("style", "display:block;z-index:999999;pointer-events:none;position:fixed;top:0");
      document.body.prepend(canvas);
      canvas.width = width;
      canvas.height = height;
      window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      }, true);
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    } else if (context === null)
      context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var count = confetti.maxCount;
    if (min) {
      if (max) {
        if (min == max)
          count = particles.length + max;
        else {
          if (min > max) {
            var temp = min;
            min = max;
            max = temp;
          }
          count = particles.length + ((Math.random() * (max - min) + min) | 0);
        }
      } else
        count = particles.length + min;
    } else if (max)
      count = particles.length + max;
    while (particles.length < count)
      particles.push(resetParticle({}, width, height));
    streamingConfetti = true;
    pause = false;
    runAnimation();
    if (timeout) {
      window.setTimeout(stopConfetti, timeout);
    }
  }

  function stopConfetti() {
    streamingConfetti = false;
  }

  function removeConfetti() {
    stop();
    pause = false;
    particles = [];
  }

  function toggleConfetti() {
    if (streamingConfetti)
      stopConfetti();
    else
      startConfetti();
  }

  function isConfettiRunning() {
    return streamingConfetti;
  }

  function drawParticles(context) {
    var particle;
    var x, y, x2, y2;
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      particle = particles[i];
      particleWidth = particle.diameter;
      x2 = particle.x + particle.tilt;
      x = x2 + particle.diameter / 2;
      y = particle.y;

      context.save();
      context.translate(x, y);
      context.rotate(particle.tilt / 180 * Math.PI);
      context.translate(-x, -y);
      context.drawImage(svg, x, y, particle.width, particle.height);
      context.restore();

   /*context.beginPath();
   context.lineWidth = particle.diameter;
   x2 = particle.x + particle.tilt;
   x = x2 + particle.diameter / 2;
   y2 = particle.y + particle.tilt + particle.diameter / 2;
   if (confetti.gradient) {
    var gradient = context.createLinearGradient(x, particle.y, x2, y2);
    gradient.addColorStop("0", particle.color);
    gradient.addColorStop("1.0", particle.color2);
    context.strokeStyle = gradient;
   } else
    context.strokeStyle = particle.color;
   context.moveTo(x, particle.y);
   context.lineTo(x2, y2);
   context.stroke();*/
    }
  }

  function updateParticles() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;
    var particle;
    waveAngle += 0.01;
    for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
      particle = particles[i];
      if (!streamingConfetti && particle.y < -15)
        particle.y = height + 100;
      else {
        particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncrement;
        particle.x += Math.sin(waveAngle) - 0.5;
        particle.y += (Math.cos(waveAngle) + particle.diameter + confetti.speed) * 0.5;
        particle.tilt = Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle) * 15;
      }
      if (particle.x > width + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > height) {
        if (streamingConfetti && particles.length <= confetti.maxCount)
          resetParticle(particle, width, height);
        else {
          particles.splice(i, 1);
          i--;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  startConfetti(5000, 20, 25)
})();
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. Would it be possible to change the rotation with alternating directions(clockwise and anti-clockwise) to make it look like a natural wavy drop. It currently rotates clockwise only. It's missing this last thing to make it look more real. Would be really glad if you could help. Thank you :)

Comment: I updated the code above, now using `tilt` not `tiltAngle` this should do what you want. But may I suggest checking out https://threejs.org/ its better than just using a canvas and it is well documented (https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Creating-a-scene)!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I actually made an attempt, but I’m not sure if it’s the correct approach. I’ve posted it here. You mind taking a look? It’s my latest post.

Comment: Where did you post it?

Comment: [Here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58670868/10301756 ), it’s my new question that I posted few hours ago.