# Three.js simple particle animation

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I'm trying to recreate the existing particle animation ([previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58658689/apply-random-rotation-to-canvas-particles)) using three.js for added perspective and 3d rotation. This is my first time using three.js and I'm having some issues on how to:

1. Randomly scatter the particles on the screen.
2. Correctly (without the black background) apply an image texture to the particles.
3. Apply the rotation just as my previous post but with some 3d touch.

Basically I'm trying to recreate what I was trying to do in my previous post on `canvas`, using three.js.

Please point me in the right direction. Thank you :)

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

camera.position.z = 10;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});

renderer.setClearColor("#343434");
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;

  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
})

var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://i.postimg.cc/rmn0cLmS/confetti.png');

for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: texture,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
  })

  var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(.5, 1 * .75);
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

  mesh.position.x = (Math.random() * (500 - 1) + 1) * Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
  mesh.position.y = (Math.random() * (window.innerHeight - 1) + 1 * Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1);
  mesh.position.z = (Math.random() * (10 - 1) + 1 * Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1);

  scene.add(mesh);
}

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF, 1, 500);

light.position.set(10, 0, 25);

scene.add(light);

var render = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  mesh.position.y -= 0.05;
  mesh.rotation.x += 0.05;
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

render();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/109/three.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok take a look at these examples from three.js [webgl_points_sprites](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_sprites) or [webgl_points_billboards](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_billboards) and their code on [github](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_points_sprites.html), they are using [Points](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Points) with the [Texture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/Texture) attached via [PointsMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial).

I suggest checking out the three.js documentation and examples and maybe some tutorials on YouTube or others, there is a lot out there and you will learn more about how all this works while researching what you need for your current project!

Comment: Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. I followed your instructions and I think I'm pretty close. Can you help me with rotation? -> https://jsfiddle.net/4f5cs12a/. It seems as if its origin is on the axis rather than the particles' center?

Comment: In your previous code you are updating the `particles` in `updateParticles` and then you are applying the values in `drawParticles`, in your new code you are not doing this at all. Maybe you need to analyse the other code and for the rotation problem maybe try some [simple examples](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-fundamentals.html). Just take small steps to understand how it works.